# (F#) Smoothest way to read all bytes from a CryptoStream

Tags: f#, stream

I'm working on a procedure for decrypting binary data using AesCryptoServiceProvider.  For the final step, retrieving the decrypted data and returning it as an array of bytes, I'm currently using the following implementation:

```
let rec streamBytes (s : CryptoStream) (b : int) = seq {
    if b >= 0 then
        yield byte b
        yield! streamBytes s (s.ReadByte()) }
streamBytes cryptoStream (cryptoStream.ReadByte())
|> Seq.toArray
```

It works, but it doesn't feel "correct" to me.  Passing the result of CryptoStream.ReadByte() as an argument to streamBytes(), and then checking is value in that recursive call seems a bit Rube Goldberg-y.  Is there a better way to be doing it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Draining stream byte by byte will be very slow.

if you have .NET 4.0 then the most straightforward way will be:

```
open System.IO

let readAllBytes (s : Stream) = 
    let ms = new MemoryStream()
    s.CopyTo(ms)
    ms.ToArray()
```

else you need to reproduce CopyTo functionality manually

```
let readAllBytes (s : Stream) =
    let ms = new MemoryStream()
    let buf = Array.zeroCreate 8192
    let rec impl () = 
        let read = s.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length) 
        if read > 0 then 
            ms.Write(buf, 0, read)
            impl ()
    impl ()
```

Comment: I hadn't been concerned with performance because the amount of data to process should be very small, but I suppose it is wise to be prepared.  And extra thanks for making me aware of .NET 4's Stream.CopyTo().

Comment: Oh, one nitpick I just realized - that MemoryStream should be declared using 'use' instead of 'let' in order to make sure it's disposed of properly.

Comment: @SeanU : While I agree that _anything_ implementing `IDisposable` should be disposed, it's worth mentioning that `MemoryStream` only implements `IDisposable` because `Stream` does (i.e., its `Dispose` implementation is a no-op and only exists because it's abstract in the base class).

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason not to use `Read` instead of `ReadBytes`?  It seems like that would be much more direct.  Otherwise, your solution doesn't look too bad to me - the design of the API is pretty limiting, since you need to use the return value of `ReadByte` to determine whether to break your loop and to decide what value to output.  Here's one alternative implementation:

```
[| let currentByte = ref 0
   let moveNext() = 
       currentByte := cryptoStream.ReadByte()
       !currentByte >= 0
   while moveNext() do
       yield byte !currentByte |]
```